# How to authenticate with custom apis/microservices from using Twilio Flex SSO token

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

I have successfully enabled a plugin to work with Azure AD . And based on the  documentation I can find, Twilio encourages the idea that if you wanted to communicate from React JS app to custom APIs , then you can do so. The problem I see is that Twilio sort of ignores the fact that when  communicating to those APIs from the client app, authentication must be in place between custom apis and react plugin app

How are people unifying the authentication between the Auth that takes place at the UI later and subsequent requests that are mare to backend apis? Can we reuse the token?

Within the https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/users/single-sign-on I see

[image]

Does this mean OAuth support is coming? Where can I post this question to increase the likelyhood of receiving some indicators as to which protocols are going to be supported in the near future? If twilio flex team is in fact working on adding OAuth support, I would imagine it would only benefit them to let the community know, especially those with existing microservices and OAuth based flow already preconfigured.

Ive added a issue here hopefully to get some response on this question. 
https://github.com/twilio/twilio-flex-token-validator/issues/13

Answer (score 4):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

This is related to the [SSO tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/configuring-single-sign-and-identity-provider-integration) used within [Twilio Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57016589/how-authenticate-with-custom-apis-from-ui-component-using-twilio-sso-token/57034684?noredirect=1#comment100658977_57034684).

You can re-use the token to authenticate your plugin. To do so, you'll need to validate the token from your plugin. You can do this by sending the token to the `https://iam.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Tokens/validate` endpoint.

This endpoint is currently undocumented and not available within the Twilio helper libraries, which is why you have found it hard to find guidance on this, but here's how you use it.

You need to make an authenticated `POST` request, using your account sid and auth token (or an API key and secret) to the URL: `https://iam.twilio.com/v1/Accounts/{AccountSid}/Tokens/validate`

The body of the request should be JSON and contain one key, `token`, with the value of your SSO token.

The result will be in JSON and if the token is valid will have a key of `valid` set to `true`. If it is not, there will be a `message` field you can read to find more information.

If you are using Node.js, you are in luck as there is a module you can install to do all of this for you; the [`twilio-flex-token-validator`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-flex-token-validator). For more detail on making calls to the validation endpoint, you can check [the source code of `twilio-flex-token-validator`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-flex-token-validator/blob/master/src/index.ts). There is also [a tutorial on how to make calls to plugins from Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/call-functions-from-plugins) that gets to securing the plugin about halfway through.

Sorry it took all of this to get to this answer and it's not the greatest answer. Please let me know if this helps and how you get on.

Comment: I am specifically referring to the authentication that would happen to a custom API using a single token that is obtained upon login. Thank you for sending the example that you had. The example you provided shows how we would go about calling a Twilio Built API server side using process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN. What I am looking for is to potentially setup an API Gateway(think Amazon API Gateway,Azure API Management Service,Apigee API Gateway, etc) and then to ensure that token is valid at the gateway layer.How is your app validate token server side? Does that help to describe my problem better?

Comment: I'm a little confused. What token are you talking about in this case?

Comment: Oauth token. SAML Token.

Comment: what would be your best guess at what I am trying to accomplish? I would imagine your guess would be pretty close to what I am after. I dont believe my use case is unique.

Comment: I'm still confused, where are you getting the OAuth/SAML token from? I tried guessing with my first answer, that's why I'm after more information. The more information you can furnish me with the more likely I'll be able to help.

Comment: thank you @philnash, Ill continue to provide more information until I resolve this. One way the token can be generated is by integration Flex with SSO using Azure AD for example. Upon logging in, a token is now persisted in localstorage based on the SSO integration. Thats 1 possible scenario of a token being generated. Are you familiar with the fact that SSO integration with Azure AD leads to a token being generated?

Comment: Oh, you're using Flex! Let me look into that.

Comment: ah, I definitely missed mentioning that. Thats my bad. Yes, twilio flex.thank you.

Comment: I'm checking with the Flex team to see if there is any guidance. Will get back to you with this when I can.

Comment: I have updated my answer (well, completely changed it) with the right guidance now.  Let me know how you get on with it.

Comment: ok this is very helpful. Is there any way I can use an oauth based token so that I dont have to use a library and can instead use OAuth flow? What I would really like to know is if I can obtain an a token using something such as Azure AD, and have that be an OAuth based token. Then, I validate that token server side with the token authority.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You have the token in Flex and when you pass it to your server you then validate that token with the token authority, which is the Twilio API endpoint that I put in the answer. You don't need to use a library if you don't want to, it's just an HTTP request to validate the token. The library we built can make it easier.

Comment: Thank you philnash. So all your information has been VERY helpful. What I am hoping is that the token obtained using SSO is of type 'OAuth 2' so that this token can be validated against the identity provider directly, instead of being proxied through twilio. I see value in allowing twilio function to authenticate with the SAML token. I envision that being useful when the twilio function logic invokes twilio SDK operations. (as the demo you referenced showcases). However, what if existing REST API's are built (outside of twilio. Say microservices) and accept Oauth based tokens?

Comment: Hey Joey, I think I get what you’re saying, but I’ve just been learning about how Flex world myself over this conversation, so sorry to be slow on the uptake. This is good feedback and I’d normally offer to send this all in myself. However I’m just off on holiday for a few days right now. So, I’d recommend you get in touch with Twilio support to register this as feedback.

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my question with a screenshot of "more methods coming soon" which I am seeing on https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/users/single-sign-on. Hopefully I can find a best place to get feedback as to what they are building support for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196598/discussion-between-joey-and-philnash).